# How to remove all elements from a ListIterator and then add new ones

Tags: java, iterator

How to remove all elements from a `ListIterator` and then add new ones. I'm getting `ConcurrentModificationException` while adding into iterator at last line.

```
public static void doAction(List<String> list) {
    for (ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String s1 = iterator.next();
        if(s1.equals("XYZ")){
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
            }
            list.add("123");
            list.add("456");
            list.add("789");
            list.forEach(iterator::add);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the exception is that you're attempting to add to the list while you're iterating over it. `List#forEach` will is fail fast and will still throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` in the underlying list is structurally modified during iteration (i.e in your case the `iterator::add` action).

Now for the purposes of what you want to achieve your method can be re-written and modified like so:

```
public static void doAction(List<String> list) {
     if (list.contains("XYZ")) {
         list.clear();
         list.add("123");
         list.add("456");
         list.add("789");
     }
}
```

Which is much more straightforward and easy to follow. You simply check if the value you're looking for is present within the given list and then simply call `List#clear` which will empty the passed in one. You'll then add the new elements and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do make the noted changes.

```
    List<String> list = ArrayList<>(List.of("ABC","DEF", "GHI", "XYZ", "JKL", "MNO"));

    public static void doAction(List<String> list) {
        for (ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            String s1 = iterator.next();
            if(s1.equals("XYZ")){
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    iterator.next();
                    iterator.remove();
                }
                list.add("123");
                list.add("456");
                list.add("789");
                break;            // add this
           //     list.forEach(iterator::add);  // delete this
            }
        }
    }
```

It prints.

> [ABC, DEF, GHI, XYZ, 123, 456, 789]

But I believe a cleaner way to do it would be.

```
     List<String> list = ArrayList<>(List.of("ABC","DEF", "GHI", "XYZ", "JKL", "MNO"));

     public static void doAction(List<String> list) {
        ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().equals("XYZ")) {
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    it.next();
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        list.add("123");
        list.add("456");
        list.add("789");
     }
```